# JAXB with HTTP inbounds throws exception An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"

Tags: mule

When I have XML payload from JMS inbound, XML to JAXB works as expected. But when I have same XML payload from HTTP inbound it throws an exception

An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)

Is it not a fair expectation from "XML to JAXB" component to have a XML payload from HTTP inbound? Please let me know what I am missing here.

Flow xml with with JMS and HTTP inbound. Only JMS inbound works as expected,

```
<flow name="productdemoFlow">
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="my.test" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
<jms:transaction action="NOT_SUPPORTED"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.chc.model.Product" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
<flow name="productdemoFlow1">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
<logger message="#[&quot;Payload ----------&gt;&quot; + payload.getClass().getName()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
<logger message="#[&quot;Payload ----------&gt;&quot; + payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer encoding="windows-1252" mimeType="application/xml" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace ?

Comment: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
 at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:119)
 at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, what you see is what you would expect.

The JMS inbound endpoint follows (by default, as in your case) a "one way" pattern, there is no response message to the client so there is no special requirement for the payload at the end of the flow.

The HTTP inbound endpoint follows (by default, as in your case) a "request-response" pattern so the payload, before sending the response to the client, should be of a type managed by the endpoint. In your case it is a java object instance of a not managed type, it must be converted to a correct type (String, InputStream, byte[], ...). For example:

```
<mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however issue here is "XML to JAXB" itself fails to convert to XML payload to respective Java class and throws the exception that stops flow. So the question is why "XML to JAXB" fails with payload given via HTTP inbound? This sample code does not care about response given back but just focusing on the issue. Even if it were to work the response would be some garbage strings but not exception like this.

Comment: It fails because "XML to JAXB"  is invoked when the transformation is fired, in this case when the endpoint (http) pulls for data. The http endpoint informs the "XML to JAXB" transformer about the data type it expect ("class [B"), which it does not support.

Comment: If you activate full stack trace (-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true) you will see:
 org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
 at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:119)
[...]
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:159)
 at ***org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:97)***
[...]

Comment: Thanks José.  I see your point. That makes sense. So if I add other components before the endpoint pulls that changes the payload, it works out. Appreciate your response. Accepted your answer.